# Infinite zoom control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, zooming

How do I do in WPF/Silverlight something like this:

> [Zoom quilt](http://dagobah.net/flash/zoomquilt.swf)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [DeepZoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You could try [Microsoft Photosynth](http://photosynth.net/)

Comment: Thanks, Maybe I wans't clear enough, it's isn't a simple zoom but a lot of pictures that benn changed in a zoom way.
I putted new link, more close to what I meant.

Comment: May be `Microsoft Photosynth` ?